# Key "" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, many-to-many

I have this simple problem but since I am a beginner I need help so thank u in advance

I have a class campagne and a class groupe with a ManytoMany relation between the 2 which automatically added a campagne-groupe table that contains both their ids

now I am trying to display in a table the name of each created "campagne" with the "groupe" associated to it but i get this error :

> Key "" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.

CampagneController :

```
  public function index()
{
    $campagne= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Campagne::class)->findAll();
 //   return $this->render('campagne/index.html.twig',['campagne'=> $campagne]);

    return $this->render(
        'campagne/index.html.twig',
        array('campagne'=> $campagne )
   );
          }
```

CampagneType :

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Nom')
       
        ->add('EmailExpediteur')
        ->add('NomExpediteur')
        ->add('Message',TextareaType::class)
         ->add('campagnes')
         ->add('envoyer', SubmitType::class)
```

twig :

```
                                {% for camp in campagne %}

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ camp.Nom }}
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>

                                            {% for camp in campagne.campagnes %}
                                                {{ campagne.campagnes }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            
                                        </td>
```

I tried {{ dump(campagne) }} and i got this :

```
 array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Entity\Campagne {#620 ▼
    -id: 33
    -Nom: "camp1"
    -EmailExpediteur: "expmail@gmail.com"
    -NomExpediteur: "amani"
    -Message: "bla"
    -campagnes: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#683 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: App\Entity\Campagne {#620}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#431 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "relation1"
      -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#623 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#617 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
```

Comment: Why not post the entire app?

Answer (score 0):

You gave us 3 block of code.
The first one, from your controller is correct.
The second one is a form type, but i don't see any use of it here. Why would you share it with us? Is it used in your template?
The third one is your template which, i guess, throw the exception. It is not complete, but i can see at least one thing wrong:

```
{% for camp in campagne %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ camp.Nom }}
        </td>
        <td>
            // Big warnings here
            {% for camp in campagne.campagnes %}
                {{ campagne.campagnes }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    // I guess the end is something like this:
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The big warnings are:

- You are overwritting `camp` which was define in the first loop
- You are not using camp but campagne in your second loop

So i guess your warning come from this line: `{% for camp in campagne.campagnes %}` which should be replace by:

```
{% for camp in campagne %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ camp.Nom }}
        </td>
        <td>
            // Big warnings here
            {% for insidersCampage in camp.campagnes %}
                {{ insidersCampage.Nom}}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```